# How I combine cygwin style path (/cygdrive/) and windows version of Python?

Tags: python, cygwin

I have .sh script that executes .py script and it doesn't work giving me following error:

`C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/NewFolder/Kindle/Src_Updater/kindle_update_tool_lite.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

How can I combine cygwin style path (/cygdrive/) and windows version of Python without changing scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the python interpreter from inside cygwin POSIX environment.

Answer (score 4):

First know which python you are using.  If you need to run cygwin python you can either call it explicitly in your .sh script or add it to your system path.  Another very useful command is `cygpath`.

```
c:/Python27/python `cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/NewFolder/Kindle/Src_Updater/kindle_update_tool_lite.py`
```

Should run

```
c:/Python27/python c:\NewFolder\Kindle\Src_Updater\kindle_update_tool_lite.py
```